# Javascript evaluation order for operators

Tags: javascript, evaluation

Which of the following expressions will always precede  left to right in all browsers(particularly IE6+, F3+, Opera 9+, Chrome)?  For example the window should always alert `first function` then `second function`.  In C they always suggest not to depend on the order of the evaluation  of expressions.  Is the same true for JavaScript or is Operator Precedence consistent?

```
function first(){
    alert('first function');
    return 0;
}
function second(){
    alert('second function');
    return 23;
}
first() + second();
first() - second();
first() * second();
first() / second();
first() < second();
first() > second();
```

Using [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) it appears function evaluation should be consistent in all browsers, but obviously the standard isn't always followed.

### Testing

After some test on browsershots.org it appears all browsers follow the standard.
Generally 
The exception is when relying on the the `valueOf` method in javascript.  `ValueOf` definitely appears to be called backwards in specific cases for google chrome.

```
// The following alerts second then first in google chrome
first.valueOf = function(){alert('first');};
second.valueOf = function(){alert('second');};
first > second;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) specifies the order of evaluation of the operands for all operators. In the case of every operator in your code snip the evaluation order is left-to-right. I'm not sure anyone could answer about the behavior of *all* browsers though.

Edit: See also [ECMAScript 3.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) Evaluation order is defined the same way.

Comment: I am specifically curious about the first five operators listed above `+ - * / <`  The others are fairly unconcerning to me.

Comment: `+ - * / <` should all evaluate their operands left-to-right. `>` should also evaluate it's operands left-to-right, any *modern* javascript engine behaving differently has a bug. Sorry, I don't know the bugs of every javascript engine in every browser to fully answer this question.

Comment: @Jake: it's not a bug, it's in the ECMAScript 3rd edition specification. i updated my answer, though, as it was more subtle than i remembered.

Comment: @Claudiu: No it **is** a bug. Left-to-right operator evaluation is clearly specified for the `>` operator in the ECMAScript 3rd edition spec. Please refer to the spec I linked if you don't want to take my word for it.

Comment: @Jake: read it more closely. for `a > b`, first `a` is evaluated, resulting in `val_a`, then `b` is evaluated, resulting in `val_b` (11.8.2). that is left-to-right. **then**, `val_b $<$ val_a` is evaluated (11.8.2 [5]), where `$<$` is the primitive relational operator (11.8.5). this will convert `val_b` to a primitive (11.8.5 [1]), then `val_a` to a primitive (11.8.5 [2]). if they are objects, it will call their `valueOf` methods in that order, which is opposite from `a > b`. any browser adhering to the spec will have the behavior i outline in my answer

Comment: @Jake: ECMAScript 5 added some extra wording to fix this (see 11.8.2 and 11.8.5 there) cause it was mad wack.

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes I see what you mean. During the comparison stage of the `>` operator the ToPrimitive and possibly ToNumber 'functions' get called on b before a. If a and b are objects the valueOf and possibly toString functions may get called.

Answer (score 6):

Evaluating the expression into a value (e.g. involving a function call) is always done left to right.

However, once you are comparing two values, they are not converted into primitives in order to do the actual comparison in a left to right fashion. Try the following in Chrome, for example:

```
var l = {valueOf: function() { alert("L"); }};
var r = {valueOf: function() { alert("R"); }};

l < r; //alerts "L", then "R"
l > r; //alerts "R", then "L"
```

Comment: So what precedence do operators all agree on?

Comment: @Claudiu - Just tested that in Chrome & FF, doesn't work like that.  It's always left-to-right

Comment: I am specifically curious about the first five operators listed above `+ - * / <`  The others are fairly unconcerning to me.

Comment: @Lime: should always be left to right. the warning about C was (at least) because function calls are often done right to left, so if you do something like `i++` as one of the parameters, expecting its side effect (like `f(i++,i)`, you might be surprised.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was just about to ask about the order  when you override the valueOf method.  1 step ahead of me. :)  Is it acceptable to override the valueOf method like you did above or is it bad practice and confusing?  I have always wanted to create a `time` object with the valueOf returning the current time so I could drop the parenthesis and similar tricks.

Comment: @Lime: i think whenever the behavior can be this messed up, it would be a bad practice. i'd go for explicitly calling any conversion functions just to avoid more confusion than JavaScript usually generates

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence and order of evaluation are two entirely different things.  In the expression "sqrt(9) + sqrt(16) * sqrt(25)" it is misleading to say that "the multiplication is done first.".  It is correct to say "multiplication takes precedence over addition.".

The operations are:

1. sqrt(9)
2. sqrt(16)
3. sqrt(25)
4. 4 * 5
5. 3 + 20

The first three could be done in any order, or -- gasp -- *simultaneously* if you have a four-core CPU and a browser that can take advantage of it.  1 must be done before 5, 2 and 3 must be done before 4, and 4 must be done before 5.  There are no other guarantees.

In the expression "a && (b / a)", JavaScript guarantees that a is evaluated first and b / a is not evaluated if a is zero.  Many other languages including Fortran do not guarantee this, and can get a division-by-zero exception.

Comment: I understand C works as you describe above, but I honestly don't believe the functions occur simultaneously  in any case for javascript.  I have a four i5 processor and definitely doesn't occur like that in firefox, chrome or opera.  Javasrcript is single threaded anyways.  Only one function can occur at a time in javascript.  From the sources above there appears to be a standard, where browsers follow it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your use-case is, but this might be an option:

```
function add() {
  var retval = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    retval += arguments[i];
  }
  return retval;
}

function echoNum(num) {
  alert("Num: " + num);
  return num;
}

alert("Result: " + add(echoNum(1), echoNum(2)));
```

Comment: I'm don't have particular use case at the moment, I'm just trying to clarify the de facto standards.  Cool idea though.